# Tor Bookmarks file location

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I am trying to locate saved bookmarks on a OS X slave drive that once used Tor. Where are Tor bookmarks saved in the OS X file structure?

Answer (score 2):

Found it - it's the places.sqlite file:

```
/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/xxx.default/places.sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

The bookmarks are stored in an sqlite database *inside the application bundle*. If you right-click on the Tor Browser application and then select "Show Package Contents" from the context menu, you can see the folder structure inside the package.

The database is located at TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/places.sqlite

You can query (for example) the titles and URLs like this:

`sqlite3 /the/path/to/your/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/places.sqlite "select moz_bookmarks.title, moz_places.url from moz_bookmarks, moz_places where moz_bookmarks.fk = moz_places.id;"`

Answer (score 0):

When I find .html bookmark file to import it does not appear in TOR.   If people cannot migrate their bookmarks, they won't be likely to want to change browsers, so this is critical function to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, I was able to find and copy the bookmarks file by doing:

```
sudo apt install mlocate
locate places.sqlite | grep TorBrowser
```

Make sure the new machine's TorBrowser app is not running, then copy that file over to the new Ubuntu machine.

Start up the new machine's TorBrowser and voila!  Your bookmarks are back.