# Bookmark Removal

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, windows, help

I am on Windows 10 with TBB version 8.0.8. I extracted the bundle to my desktop and used it form there for some time (Computer A). Of note, I created some bookmarks. I then moved the TBB folder to a removable drive. When I insert that drive into another computer (Computer B) and run the TBB, the bookmarks I created are not present. Furthermore, and of concern, when I reinsert that drive into the computer that originally had TBB on the desktop (Computer A), the bookmarks are again present. This indicated to me that the current TBB is storing this information on the local machine outside of the install folder. I Would like to know where this data is stored so I may remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, TBB is a sandbox that tries to avoid any data left on the system it was running on. So, you *should* not have this experience.

See these two posts that describe where you could search for the bookmarks:
[Tor Bookmarks file location](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9108/tor-bookmarks-file-location) and [Where does Firefox store bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/71144/where-does-firefox-store-bookmarks) (because TBB is based on Firefox)

However, from the aspect of anonymity, I would suggest you to not use one TBB on different systems. Personally, I use one instance on every device.